# Adding new field in point layer with attribute from another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, expression, point-in-polygon

I'm working with QGIS 3.16 Hannover under MacOS 10.13 environment. I've got a point and a polygon shapefile layers.

I want to add a new field to my point layer with the `"id"` of the polygon that contains it. Is it possible to do so with the field calculator, instead of creating a new layer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> This plugin is deprecated!
>
> The plugin is outdated as of QGIS 3.14 due to the introduction of the new functions for geometry overlay expressions

You can use ["refFunctions"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) Plugin. It adds custom user functions to QGIS Field Calculator. Then, you can add a new field to the point layer with the id of the polygon that contains it using the following expression in Field Calculator for the point layer:

```
geomwithin('polygon_layer_name', 'id_field_of_polygon_layer')
```

[image]

Comment: Fortunately, you mentioned the arguments required in the "geomwithin" function, as its help isn't available.

Answer (score 11):

There is also a possibility without need to install a plugin, simply using this expression. [`overlay_within()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-within) is available since QGIS 3.16, in fact implementing the functions of the refFunctions plugin in QGIS natively: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/#port-reffunctions-to-core

```
array_to_string(overlay_within('polygon', id))
```

The first argument of the [`overlay_within()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-within) function is the layer it refers to, the second one an expression executed on this layer (here: simply a field name). Add the function [`to_int()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#to-int) to get an integer instead of a string as output type.

[image]

Comment: Although needing to install a complement, I find easier to implement the solution proposed by @Kadir Şahbaz. Not clear for me the arguments required by the overlay_within function

Comment: Full syntax of the function is: `overlay_within(layer[,expression][,filter][,limit][,cache=false])` - parts in brackets [] are optional. So the first argument is the layer you want to refer to (here: `polygon`), the second one the expression, here: `id` (as you want to get the `id` of the layer `polygon`). The expression enginge has a very good help that explains syntax/arguments in detail.

Answer (score 3):

Currently a bit "old-fashioned" approach using the [`aggregate()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#aggregate) function:

```
aggregate(
    layer:='polygon_layer',
    aggregate:='concatenate',
    concatenator:=',',
    expression:=to_string("id"),
    filter:=contains($geometry, geometry(@parent))
    )
```