# Returning polygon attributes intersecting a buffer

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, turf

I am trying to return attributes of polygons (from the SAC feature) that intersect the buffer created around the route, but I keep getting:

> Uncaught Error: geojson must be a valid Feature or Geometry

Here is my code:

```
/*OVERLAYS*/
var SAC = L.geoJson({{ sac }} , {

 style: function(feature) {
return {
  color: "black",
  fill:'url(img/image.gif)',
   weight: 1,

  opacity: 0.8
};
},

onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
   const p = feature.properties
p.title  = p.SAC_NAME || p.name 
layer.on('mouseover', function() {
  this.setStyle({
    'fillColor': '#0000ff'
  });
});
layer.on('mouseout', function() {
  this.setStyle({
    'fillColor': 'transparent'
  });
});
//mouse tooltip properties
if (p && p.name) {
  layer.bindTooltip(p.name, {
    closeButton: false,
    offset: L.point(0, -20)
  });
  layer.on('mouseover', function() {
    layer.openPopup();
  });
  layer.on('mouseout', function() {
    layer.closePopup();
    });
  }
 }
  })
```

Add buffer layer around route:

```
document.getElementById('radius').onchange = function() {
 var radius = parseInt(document.getElementById('radius').value);
  //  if (isNaN(radius)) radius = 500;
 var buffered = turf.buffer(PreferredTerrestrialRoute.toGeoJSON(), radius , {units: 'kilometres'});
 map.removeLayer(roadbuf);/* remove existing laer*/


roadbuf = new L.GeoJSON(buffered, {

style: function(feature) {
return {
  color: "green",
  fill:"green",
   weight: 1,
       //  fillColor: "transparent",
       //   color: "blue",

  opacity: 0.8
};
 },
})
map.addLayer(roadbuf)  

var polyintersect = turf.intersect(SAC.toGeoJSON(), roadbuf.toGeoJSON());
    console.log( polyintersect.features.length +" points in this poly");
    alert("results "+JSON.stringify(ptsWithin4));

}
```

Comment: There is a lot of code. At which line you are getting the error?

Comment: @TomazicM this line var polyintersect = turf.intersect(SAC.toGeoJSON(), roadbuf.toGeoJSON());
    console.log( polyintersect.features.length +" points in this poly");
    alert("results "+JSON.stringify(ptsWithin4));

Comment: Are you trying to do something similar to this and could that help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/388414/88814

Comment: `turf.intersect` expects two GeoJSON polygons, so there is something wrong with either `SAC.toGeoJSON()` or `roadbuf.toGeoJSON()`. Examine contents of those two.